# Facebook Send/Like button CSS overlapping

Tags: css, overlap

I have following problem. I've integrated facebook send/like buttons to my website and when i click send, it overlaps with the underlying div.

Since I'm really no CSS guru, i would like that you point me in to a direction where i can find a solution for this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the div with class `box-center` & div with class `box` have the css property `overflow: hidden;` so anything that's bigger then the div when is loaded will not be shown

but the problem if you remove that is that the box above will be messed up. But that can be resolved by adding (just before closing the div):

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

and in css

```
.clear {clear:both}
```

edit: This should give you a better picture (for a bigger preview -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvsJW.png)

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your quick response :) I did that and experimented in some kind of ways but, the issue still remains. Could you check if i applied it correctly?

Comment: no you didn't place the div in the right spot, it should be in the div.box above. See the screenshot I added, should make it clear :)